# Remove items from a list using a boolean array

Tags: python, list

I'm removing some columns from a numpy array using a boolean array. Is it possible to do something similar with a list?

```
#Set a numpy array of booleans to True if column datatype is "Categorical"
cols_to_remove = np.array([datatype == "Categorical" for datatype in datatypes])

#Make a new array without the "Categorical" columns
cat_data = data[:, -cols_to_remove] # data here is a 2D numpy array

#Trying to do the same for a list - this way doesn't work
cat_datatypes = datatypes[-cols_to_remove] # datatypes here is a 1D list
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with a list comprehension:

```
In [17]: cols_to_remove = [False, False, True, False, True, False]

In [18]: [d for (d, remove) in zip(datatypes, cols_to_remove) if not remove]
Out[18]: ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f']
```

It `cols_to_remove` is an array of indices, the following solution can be use:

```
In [12]: datatypes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

In [13]: cols_to_remove = [2, 4]

In [14]: [d for (i, d) in enumerate(datatypes) if i not in cols_to_remove]
Out[14]: ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f']
```

Here, for efficiency reasons it may be a good idea to turn `cols_to_remove` into a `set`.

Comment: I'm actually using `cat_datatypes = [d for d in datatypes if d != "Categorical"]`, I was just interested to know if there's a way to do it using the `cols_to_remove` boolean array. The first part of your answer looks like what I was looking for.

Comment: @JamieBull in appears to be popular enough to have made it into the standard `itertools`in Python 3.1 - http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress